# Visual Studio 2015 Installation issues

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I am working on some very old software that uses Visual Studio 6, Visual Studio .net and Visual Studio 2010.  So I ended up having to install various versions of studio from 6 all the way to 2017.  At some point something got messed up and I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling a whole bunch of things.  Everything else works now, but Visual Studio 2015 is toast.  I uninstalled anything related to 2015, then reinstalled it.  Same problem.  Uninstalled it again, hoping the uninstaller would correctly remove stuff, reinstall, again no go.

So, when I open VS, the log in button on the top right does nothing.  If I try to create a test C++ project, it just closes the screen where you enter the project details and then reopens it, no joy there.  If I open a solution with C++ projects in it is says it does not know how to load the project file of that  type.

If I build the project in VS 2017 and leave the projects as VS 2015, I get a linker error "LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'mfc140d.lib'", so something mostly likely did not install properly.

After clicking on the log in button, the other menu's will highlight when you click on then, but no menu's.

The ActivityLog.xml contains stuff like this:

```
      <entry>
    <record>366</record>
    <time>2017/08/08 14:18:48.820</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Extension Manager</source>
    <description>Error loading extension: This VSIX does not apply to any product installed on this machine. The problem could be that the VSIX manifest&apos;s format is not recognized, or that the manifest has been corrupted. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. </description>
    <path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\VSGRAPHICS\</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>367</record>
    <time>2017/08/08 14:18:49.123</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Extension Manager</source>
    <description>Extension will not be loaded because an extension with the same ID &apos;Microsoft.Windows.DevelopmentKit.Desktop&apos; is already loaded at C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS KITS\10\DESKTOP SDK\...</description>
    <path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS KITS\8.1\DESKTOP SDK\</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>368</record>
    <time>2017/08/08 14:18:49.123</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Extension Manager</source>
    <description>Extension will not be loaded because an extension with the same ID &apos;Microsoft.Windows.DevelopmentKit.WindowsStore&apos; is already loaded at C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS KITS\10\WINDOWS STORE SDK\...</description>
    <path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS KITS\8.1\WINDOWS STORE SDK\</path>
  </entry>
```

I am guessing I might have to uninstall VS 2015 and then manually clean up any remnants?  Any suggestions?  I really don't want to rebuild this machine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know it isn't a helpful answer, but the error messages suggest your registry etc. is beyond repair. The fastest and safest way to clean up is formatting the disks and reinstalling Windows from scratch.
For your next attempt to use Visual Studio I strongly recommend virtual machines, one for each VS version.

Comment: Sadly, the build process for this product requires three of those versions of VS on the same PC.  I do have VM's for other things, but of course I don't have a i9 or thread ripper with 128 gigs of memory or something :-), this is just a corporate dev machine after all.  But you may be right.  Just before I have to do that  though, I hope to find a good blog on how to manually remove all remnants VS 2015.  I have done that for VS 6 before.